# Google Maps Qt client with heat map

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps

I am writing a Google Maps (and Open Street Maps) client in QT without QML. In principle it is easy to do with QGraphicsWebView. My problem comes because I am trying to overlay some information (a heat map, locators, etc) on it.

I have tried to link the QGraphicsWebView object to a QGraphicsScene, but I don't know how to make the heat map and the locators to be "attached" to the map coordinates, so they behave properly when the user moves the map, zooms in/out, etc.

Is there any way to make graphical elements to be associated to the maps coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

For the locators = markers you can define a Component

```
Component {
        id: marker
        Image{
            source: "your_marker.png"
            width: 40
            height: 40
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        }
    }
```

Then within the Map { } environment you can set up a MapItemView. Therein you can reference the position of the marker.